# Legitimate uses of the trailing return type syntax as of C++14

Tags: c++, c++14, trailing-return-type, return-type-deduction

Is there actually any reason to use the following syntax anymore :

```
template<typename T>
auto access(T& t, int i)
  -> decltype(t[i])
{
    return t[i];
}
```

Now that we can use :

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) access(T& t, int i)
{
    return t[i];
}
```

The trailing return type syntax now seems a little redundant?

Comment: Maybe it is just me but I sometimes want to look at function definitions and immediately know what it is going to return without looking at the implementation

Comment: You are not the only one, C++ compilers often like that as well... they get confused quite easily with early implementations of new standards features. (Or rather: compiler A trips up over code which compiler B understands, and vice versa...)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Deduced return types are not SFINAE friendly. This overload will simply drop out of the overload set if `t[i]` is invalid:

```
template<typename T>
auto access(T& t, int i)
  -> decltype(t[i])
{
    return t[i];
}
```

Whereas this overload will not, leading to a hard error:

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) access(T& t, int i)
{
    return t[i];
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/XuQX3c)

---

Also, you can run into issues with conflicting deduced return types. Consider if I wanted to return a `std::optional<T>`. The following code doesn't compile since `std::nullopt_t` is not the same type as `std::optional<T>`:

```
#include <optional> // C++17 standard library feature

template <typename T>
auto foo(T const& val)
{
    if (val.is_invalid()) return std::nullopt;
    return val.some_function_returning_an_optional();
}
```

Trailing return types let you specify exactly which expressions' type to return:

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(T const& val)
    -> decltype(val.some_function_returning_an_optional())
{
    if (val.is_invalid()) return std::nullopt;
    return val.some_function_returning_an_optional();
}
```

You could use a leading return type, but it would require the use of `std::declval`, which makes it harder to understand:

```
template <typename T>
decltype(std::declval<T const&>().some_function_returning_an_optional())
foo(T const& val)
{
    if (val.is_invalid()) return std::nullopt;
    return val.some_function_returning_an_optional();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dRA1hH)

Comment: The second example isn't good because you can just do normal leading return type. I feel like expression sfinae is all that's left.

Comment: @NirFriedman It's a simplified example, but I've encountered a case where it saves me. The return type depended on the arguments, but it was also an optional. It would be possible to use a leading return type, but not nice at all. I'll improve the second example

Comment: Well, when we have concepts and use them thoroughly, return-type-deduction will have an upswing, as we get SFINAE through that instead. It will probably only need a few decades.

Comment: @Deduplicator It probably depends on the case. For ad-hoc constraints, `-> decltype(t[i])` is much shorter than `requires requires(T const& v, int i) { v[i]; }`. But if certain constraints are used enough, they'd probably be turned into named concepts, which will work just fine.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, at least three reasons:

1. **Meaningful declaration**: Your first variant has a *declaration* which tells me what the return type is; your second variant requires that I read your *definition*. But your definition might be in another file, or not very clear.
2. **Type constraint or type conversion**: Your body could be returning something other than the expression `T[i]`, and thus you get a type constraint or a conversion from what the body returns to what you want to get.
3. **Backwards compatibility**: This may seem trivial to you, but try writing a library and telling your users "Oh, you need a C++14-conformant compiler because of my cute syntax choices".

And there's also a fourth reason in [Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52123393/1593077).