# How is this kind of template function called?

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me what kind of template function `_Fn()` is? And what is the meaning of the `->` here?

```
template <class _Ty0, class _Ty1>
struct _Common_type
{
  template<class _Uty0, class _Uty1>
  static auto _Fn(int) -> decay<decltype(false ? declval<_Uty0>() : declval<_Uty1>())>;

  template<class, class>
  static auto _Fn(_Wrap_int) -> _Nil;

  typedef decltype(_Fn<_Ty0, _Ty1>(0)) type;
};
```

Comment: `Type f()` can be written as `auto f() -> Type`.

Comment: `auto f() -> returnType` is trailing return type notation.

Comment: Guys. Guys. Guys. ANSWER SECTION OMG!

Comment: "How is it called?" In the sense of  "what is the name of that?" or "how to call the function?" I first understood the latter, but it seems the question is about the first

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Duplicates. Duplicates. Duplicates. Not scattered answers.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this function:

```
void foo()
{}
```

We can also write it like this:

```
auto foo() -> void
{}
```

It's a *trailing return type*, [introduced in C++11](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/introduction_to_the_c_11_feature_trailing_return_types?lang=en).

In the above example it's completely pointless, but [in more complicated scenarios it's useful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52123331/560648). Imaging your return type were not `void`, but something relating to the arguments ([e.g. `decltype(someArgument)`](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/11/trailing-return-types-everywhere/)). Some people just use this form all the time for "[consistency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11215227/560648)" (even on `main`! Ew!)<sup>†</sup>.

Now follow this logic all the way out to your more complex function template declaration, and that's all you're seeing.

<sub><sup>†</sup> Indeed, it appears to me that this is what the author of your code has done, since it doesn't seem "necessary" in your exampe.</sub>